# How to convert .EMF to .SVG file in c#

Tags: svg, image-conversion, .emf

I have windows form application which already have emf files in database. Currently I am converting .emf to .png and display as image but I need to convert .emf to .svg file which I can display on web app.

P.S. Conversion will be done in API side which is written under .Net framework(C#)

How can I achieve?

Comment: "Conversion will be done in API side which is written under .Net framework(C#)" - are you currently writing this API or are you using this API? Can you share some code for it?

Comment: There seem to be .Net libraries available that do what you want.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: It's probably not much help, as it's java-based, but I've implemented a .emf renderer as part of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html). If you don't find anything else, give it a try to see if it can convert your .emfs correctly (there are lots of cases, which I haven't yet implemented ...). If the output is ok, you can start to think if bringing in the 60 MB of the JRE + another ~30MB for the libraries is worth it ...

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Can you please provide any libraries link?

Comment: @Hoargarth, meaning Conversion of .emf to .svg will be done at API side.

Comment: @JatinDave Found by googling. Not used it. https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net/conversion/emf-to-svg